# Integral of $(T+dt)^{4}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to take the anti derivative of $\frac{dq}{dt}=\beta \Delta T - (T+ \Delta T)^{4}$. I'm not sure how to go at it. I want to put it as $\frac{dq}{dt}=\beta dT - (T+ dT)^{4}$. I am worried about the $\int(T+ dT)^{4}$: is this the same as $\int(T+ 1)^{4}dt$?
Thanks.

Comment: That's not how any of it works at all.

Comment: I don't really see what it means to have a differential equation: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}=\beta\cdot\mathrm{d}t-(T+\mathrm{d}T)^4$$It's kinda meaningless. I dislike the Leibnizian notation for this reason. Maybe I'm just being silly though. But in particular it's weird / wrong to have $d(-)/d(-)$ on the left hand side but just $d(-)$ on the right hand side